# MySQL error when i add apostraphe in form

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

I am trying to add an apostrophe into a form which then saves to a Database, however the form will not save when the apostrophe is added.

This is my code:

```
           <?php

$abouttitle=$_POST[abouttitle];
$aboutcontent=$_POST[aboutcontent];
$aboutside=$_POST[aboutside];
$aboutsidetitle=$_POST[aboutsidetitle];  

  $con= mysql_connect("localhost","XXX","XXX");
  if (!$con) 
  {
   die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
   }

   mysql_select_db("cl49-XXX", $con);
$result =   

$aboutcontent = mysql_real_escape_string($aboutcontent);
$abouttitle = mysql_real_escape_string($abouttitle);
$aboutside = mysql_real_escape_string($aboutside);
$aboutsidetitle = mysql_real_escape_string($aboutsidetitle); 

$query = "
UPDATE ADMIN
SET aboutcontent='$aboutcontent',
    abouttitle='$abouttitle',
    aboutside='$aboutside',
    aboutsidetitle='$aboutsidetitle'
");
$result = mysql_query($query);
```

when i add an apostrophe into the form to save it to the DB I get the below error

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
```

Comment: You should escape your data. You're indirectly SQL injecting your self. Another single quotation is probably added and thus one is missing. It needs to be escaped.

Comment: You will need to escape any single quotes, `'`. `mysql_real_escape_string` will work although you should really be using a different database library to avoid SQL injection.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Use [`mysql_real_escape_string`](http://php.net/mysql_real_escape_string) before executing your query:

```
$aboutcontent = mysql_real_escape_string($aboutcontent);
$abouttitle = mysql_real_escape_string($abouttitle);
$aboutside = mysql_real_escape_string($aboutside);
$aboutsidetitle = mysql_real_escape_string($aboutsidetitle);
```

Once you've escaped the variables, you can execute your query:

```
$query = "
UPDATE ADMIN
SET aboutcontent='$aboutcontent',
    abouttitle='$abouttitle',
    aboutside='$aboutside',
    aboutsidetitle='$aboutsidetitle'
";
$result = mysql_query($query);
```

---

**Sidenote:** [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). Learn about [*prepared statements*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo), or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Comment: I have added this code, See edited question. But i now get `Server Error`?

Comment: @Shane: [Turn on error reporting](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6575502/1438393)

Comment: I have added this but still get `server error`?

Comment: @Shane: Oops. It was an extra bracket at the end of the MySQL query. I've edited the answer. But, if you have enabled error reporting, you should have seen the error message.

Comment: Thanks, I have added the updated code, which removes the error. Now the form isnt saving any changes?

Comment: @Shane: That's not very descriptive. First of all, you should enable error reporting. Try to debug and find the error. Do a `print_r($_POST)` and see if you're getting the form inputs correctly.  Also, try executing the MySQL query directly (in your terminal/shell/phpMyAdmin) and see if it works. If it does, it's probably something wrong in your script.

Comment: Now i am very confused, i added this in and it showed everything correct however not updated the DB...

Answer (score 1):

you need to escape your `values` from the php side use a function like

`mysqli_real_escape_string` if your using the mysqli extension or

`mysql_real_escape_string` if your using the `mysql` extension